# XML File generated with DOMDocument not showing encoding

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, domdocument, xmldom

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->xmlStandalone = true;
$doc->loadXML($error);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<error status="fatal" httpResponseCode="500" httpResponseMessage="Internal Server Error">
        <errorType>InternalServerError</errorType>
        <errorServer>FeedServer</errorServer>
        <errorMessage>Failed to process GetFeed request</errorMessage>
        <friendlyMessage/>
        <innerMessage>No permitted outlet found</innerMessage>
</error>
```

I need the XML output should show the encoding="UTF-8" along with the version="1.0"
Please help...

AFTER FIXED.....

```
$doc    = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML($error);
$doc->xmlStandalone = true;
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8';
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

THE DESIRED OUTPUT...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error status="fatal" httpResponseCode="500" httpResponseMessage="Internal Server Error">
        <errorType>InternalServerError</errorType>
        <errorServer>FeedServer</errorServer>
        <errorMessage>Failed to process GetFeed request</errorMessage>
        <friendlyMessage/>
        <innerMessage>No permitted outlet found</innerMessage>
</error>
```

Comment: http://devzone.zend.com/1538/php-dom-xml-extension-encoding-processing/ this should help you

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have got some good ideas about XMLDOM from your link but my problem is not solved yet. I tried a number of things from here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in the `new DOMDocument` constructor are overwritten with the values from the loaded XML document when `loadXML` is called.

If you set the encoding of the output document (e.g. `$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'`, before calling `saveXML`), it should be added to the XML declaration.

Comment: Thanks..It works :) :)

Im uploading the final code.